# How to resolve grails plugins dependencies

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, dependency-management, shiro

My grails app should work with two plugins: [shiro](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro) and [quartz2](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz2).

I'm add both of plugins to **BuildConfig.groovy**:

- compile ":shiro:1.1.4"
- compile ":quartz2:2.1.6.2"

*(after that ide downloaded them)*

The problem in dependencies: shiro depends from **shiro-quartz:1.2.0** and **shiro-quartz** from **org.opensymphony.quartz 1.6.1**

I wonder why but quartz2 looking for methods implementation to **quartz-1.6.1.jar**.
Quartz2 cannot find implementations and that's why project cannot be build.
I think quartz2 should search methods implementations in "normal" quartz lib, like **quartz:1.0-RC7**, but he do not.

So, how can i solve shiro and quartz2 plugins conflict?

I heard about dependency excluding, but i not sure about this sugesstion.

P.S. with quartz(not quartz2) the same problem occurred

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run `dependency-report` to check what dependencies the plugins are trying to add to your project. The problem seems to be that shiro-quartz depends on quartz 1.x and quartz plugin uses quartz 2.x.

Normally you could do:

```
compile (":shiro:1.1.4") {
  excludes('org.opensymphony.quartz:quartz')
}
```

But there's a bug, and this transitive dependency isn't excluded. There's an [open ticket](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9665#comment-75475) to adjust this.

The good thing is that there's a workaround:

```
compile (":shiro:1.1.4") {
  excludes([name: 'quartz', group: 'org.opensymphony.quartz'])
}
```

With this, Grails will use Quartz 2.x only.